# What's the type of the object of "I don't remember having seen him."?

Tags: grammar

> I don't remember having seen him.

The object is *having seen him*. What kind of an object is this? Any term? I would like to read more about adjectives of this kind. Links are truly appreciated. Can you give a couple of more examples with different verbs?

P.S.

I know it's a gerund phrase. My problem is with *having ...*, which is like the combination of a present perfect and a gerund.

Comment: Huddleston & Pullum (2005) don't consider it an object. They call it a gerund-participial clause functioning as a catenative complement. A gerund-participial clause does not normally function as an object, but it can when it is followed by a predicative complement:e.g. "I find **talking to Max** rather stressful".

Comment: @user178049 My problem is with *having ...*, which is like the combination of a present perfect and gerund.

Comment: Perfect is a construction. Gerund-participle is a verb form. They don't belong to the same group. I would just say "having" is a gerund-participle verb that is used in the perfect construction.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a [gerund phrase.](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerundphrase.htm)

Gerunds are a conjugation of a verb that *acts* like a noun.  A gerund phrase is a noun phrase that starts with a gerund.  Example:

> She enjoys **writing in her journal** and **answering questions on ELL**.

In the same way that you can say something like:

> I don't remember *yesterday's lesson*

where "yesterday's lesson" is the object of "remember", you can also use a gerund phrase as the object:

> I don't remember **turning off the TV before I came upstairs**.  Can you check that it's off?

Comment: My problem is with *having ...*, which is like the combination of a present perfect and gerund.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "having seen him" is a gerund phrase in this example.   Yes, it exhibits the perfect aspect in the same way that a finite present perfect construction does.

> I have seen him. 
>   I remember having seen him.

Working from the inside out, "him" is the object of the verb *to see*.   The form of the verb *to see* in both of these examples is the so-called past-participle form, "seen".   The resulting participial phrase "seen him" in turn acts as the object of the verb *to have*.

This general pattern holds across all tenses:

> I had seen him.   -- past perfect
>   I have seen him.   -- present perfect
>   I will have seen him.   -- future perfect

It works even when there is no tense:

> having seen him   -- perfect gerund phrase or perfect present participial phrase
>   to have seen him   -- perfect infinitive phrase

It even works when the finite verb is a modal auxiliary:

> I may have seen him.
>   I might have seen him.
>   I should have seen him.

Your example isn't a combination of the ***present*** perfect and the gerund.   Neither the gerund nor the so-called *present participle* have any ***tense***.

You're looking at the combination of a ***tenseless*** verb form and the *perfect **aspect***.